# Devexpress GridView crazy MouseDown event

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, mousedown

When I implement the MouseDown event of the GridView, after I click on anything inside the GridView my program goes nuts and starts to treat everything on the screen as GridView, calling the MouseDown event wherever I click. I am not really sure why it does that but I found this code snippet:

```
    GridHitInfo downHitInfo = null;

    private void view_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        downHitInfo = null;
        GridHitInfo hitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
        if (Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.None) return;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && hitInfo.RowHandle >= 0)
            downHitInfo = hitInfo;

    }
```

which prevents that. However, I am still not really sure why this prevents that insanity. Any ideas about what's going on is appreciated

Comment: MouseDown event works as expected without the provided code snippet. I am using DX version 12.2.7.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: The behavior you described is very strange and all the ideas about its reasons are only ideas. If you want to get the exact answer you should register this issue(with sample) at [DevExpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center) instead of posting it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the event is registered on the form... not the gridcontrol

Comment: Nope that's not the case but maybe somehow its getting registered there not really sure

Comment: Well, the behavior you describe is consistent with that. 
As Rok comments, this is not normal behavior of a  devex grid.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check if the hit was in a cell of a row using `hitInfo.InRowCell`, like this :

```
GridView view = sender as GridView;
GridHitInfo hitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

// Verify that the click was in a cell of a row, if not, don't do anything
if (!hitInfo.InRowCell)
    return;
```

PS : You can use `e.Location` instead of creating a new point `new Point(e.X, e.Y)`

```
GridHitInfo hitInfo = view.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
```